# Fragment content not appearing on handset

Tags: java, android, xml, android-fragments, android-activity

I'm trying to get my fragment to appear on my handset but it won't do so for some reason. However when loading the same thing on a tablet it appears as normal. Does anyone what is wrong with my code and how to resolve this issue? All relevant help would be appreciated.

**Links to classes**

[FragmentWCLine.java](http://pastebin.com/zNyYQ9x2)

[WCBankActivity.java](http://pastebin.com/1WqihfHS)

[FragmentWCBank.java](http://pastebin.com/RycENGmS)

[WCBankViewPagerAdapter.java](http://pastebin.com/BYr8Qf0Y)

**Links to layouts**

[fragment_wc_line.xml](http://pastebin.com/NwC74pgN)

[fragment_wc_bank.xml](http://pastebin.com/NFqrcLg7)

Comment: Is it the same when viewing the app on your tablet in portrait mode?

Comment: @Simas Yep, on my tablet it works perfectly fine but on my phone it doesn't

Comment: @Simas I don't think orientation is the problem here

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In `FragmentWCBank`, you should be using the child fragment manager.

```
adapter =  new WCBankViewPagerAdapter(getChildFragmentManager(), Numboftabs, getActivity());
```

Comment: Intriguing but, Excellent! Problem solved! I never thought to change `getSupportFragmentManager()` as I honestly thought the word 'support' had to be used to support pre-Lollipop devices so many thanks for that and well done for finding the error :-D

Comment: You never want to use an `Activity` fragment manager in a `Fragment`. `getSupportFragmentManager()` is only need at the `Activity` level. When you're adding a `Fragment` inside of another `Fragment` it's called nested, and you **must** use `getChildFragmentManager()` instead.

Answer (score -1):

Please make sure that you have not designed the layout in landscape mode for android phones, then question arises how to manage in tablets.

Put this boolean resource in res/values as bools.xml or whatever (file names don't matter here):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>
    <bool name="portrait_only">true</bool>
</resources>
```

Put this one in res/values-sw600dp and res/values-xlarge:

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>
    <bool name="portrait_only">false</bool>
</resources>
```

Then on java side check the either condition like

```
if(getResources().getBoolean(R.bool.portrait_only)){
    setRequestedOrientation(ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_PORTRAIT);
}
```

Comment: I haven't designed the layout specifically for either mode at all

Answer (score -2):

Can u please include the XML Files,this problem is because of the screen resolutions,so u have to create separate XML files for different screens, To adjust the Screen Compatibility.